# Proc not found on runtime dlls like MSVCR120.dll & MSVCP120.dll

Tags: winapi, dll, windows-server-2016, nano-server

I am using **NanoServerApiScan.exe** to scan my binaries for the nano server support. It returns Errors like the following,

```
KERNEL32.dll
  CopyFileA(Proc not found)
    Please use API CopyFileExA as substitution.
  MoveFileExA(Proc not found)
    Please use API MoveFileExW as substitution.
ADVAPI32.dll
  LogonUserW(Proc not found)
    Please use API LogonUserExExW as substitution.
```

I can follow the suggestions to make my binaries work on nano servers. The scan also return errors in MSVCR120.dll and MSVCP120.dll,

```
MSVCR120.dll
    __crt_debugger_hook(Proc not found)
    __crtUnhandledException(Proc not found)
    __crtTerminateProcess(Proc not found)
    _onexit(Proc not found)
MSVCP120.dll
    ?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ(Proc not found)
    ?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPEBD@Z(Proc not found)
    ??0id@locale@std@@QEAA@_K@Z(Proc not found)
```

How to fix these kind of errors? Can the reverse forwarders package reroute these APIs also? What if my customer doesn't configure his server with reverse forwarders?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe the Nano Server only supports running code that links against the Universal CRT. You appear to be linking against the runtime that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: So, your code makes use of those functions in the pointed DLLs, but the versions that come with Nano are somehow stripped and only export a subset of what the regular versions do (at least this is my guess). The 1st symbol seems to be debug related. Do you by any chance have a _Debug_ build (not likely), or use debug stuff? Also is your _VStudio_ version (seems like it's _2k13_) compatible with _Nano_? In theory those "errors" should go away by tweaking some compiler/linker flags.

Comment: @CristiFati Yeah you are correct. The NanoServerApiScan.exe that I was using is a older one.. my binary actually ran perfectly on nano with the suggested changes.